# Create multiple records from nested Prisma transaction?

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I have the following Prisma query that runs at user registration that creates the user Account as well as creates the Team they will belong to.

```
prisma.account.create({
  data: {
    team: {
      create: { name: team_name },
    },
    username,
    email,
    password
  },
})
```

However, users also need to verify their team creation over email. To do this I have a third database table that I need to create a record for, the prisma Schema being:

```
prisma.team_verification.create({
  data: {
    team: {
      connect: {
        team_id,
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Is there any way I can merge these two queries, so that at the time of registration I create a new Team, a new "account" with team_id = the new Team, and a new "team_verification" with team_id = the new Team?

Comment: Could you share your schema if possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Interactive Transactions.
As this is a previewFeature you should config this in the generator client.

```
generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["interactiveTransactions"]
}
```

And then:

```
const user: User = await prisma.$transaction(async (prisma) => {

   let user= await prisma.account.create({
    data: {
      team: {
        create: { name: team_name },
      },
      username,
      email,
      password
    },
  })
  
  prisma.team_verification.create({
   data: {
    team: {
     connect: { user.id }
    },
   },
 })

  return user

})
```